# Amazon EC2 multiple servers share session state

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a bunch of EC2 servers that are load balanced.
Some of the servers are not sharing session, and users keep getting logged in and out.

How can I make all the server share the one session,
possibly even using a partitionresolver solution

```
    public class PartitionResolver : System.Web.IPartitionResolver
    {
        private String[] partitions;

        public void Initialize()
        {
            // create the partition connection string table
            //                           web1,            web2
            partitions = new String[] { "192.168.1.1" };
        }

        public String ResolvePartition(Object key)
        {
            String oHost = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower().Trim();

            if (oHost.StartsWith("10.0.0") || oHost.Equals("localhost"))
                return "tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424";

            String sid = (String)key;

            // hash the incoming session ID into
            // one of the available partitions
            Int32 partitionID = Math.Abs(sid.GetHashCode()) % partitions.Length;

            return ("tcpip=" + partitions[partitionID] + ":42424");
        }
    }
```

-theo

Comment: You could try using a sql server to store your session data. Its not the most efficient but when you take into consideration the different kinds of EC2 instances available it could work you better for you.

Comment: I prefer to keep it off the SQL for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gopenath/Page107182007032219AM/Page1.aspx